# Why does my sailsjs service return "undefined" to the calling controller action?

Tags: node.js, function, service, express, sails.js

I have to POST to an API that someone else has developed in order to obtain an authorization code, and as I have to do it in several different contexts I thought I'd move the code for handling the POST and getting the response to a service.

The frustrating thing at the moment is that I seem to be getting back the value that I want from the API, but can't return it from the server to the calling sails controller.

Here's the service source code:

```
module.exports = {
  getVerifyCode: function(uuid, ip_addr) {
    console.log (uuid);
    console.log (ip_addr);
    var http = require('http'),
    querystring = require('querystring'),
    // data to send
    send_data = querystring.stringify({
      uuid : uuid,
      ip_addr : ip_addr 
    }),
    // options for posting to api
    options = {
      host: sails.config.api.host,
      port: sails.config.api.port,
      path: '/verifyCode/update',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(send_data)
      }
    },
    json_output = "",
    // post request
    post_req = http.request(options, function(post_res) {
      post_res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        json_output += chunk;
      });
      post_res.on('end', function() {
        var json_data = JSON.parse(json_output),
        verify_code = json_data.verify_code;

        console.log("code="+verify_code);
        return ('vc='+verify_code);
      });
     });
    post_req.write(send_data);
    post_req.end();
  }
}
```

And here's two relevant lines from my controller action:

```
    var vc = verify.getVerifyCode(req.session.uuid, req.connection.remoteAddress);
    console.log('vc='+vc);
```

The weird thing is that the controller console log gets written before the service one does:

```
vc=undefined
code=YoAr3ofWRIFGpoi4cRRehP3eH+MHYo3EogvDNcrNDTc=
```

Any ideas?  I have a much simpler service running (just some string manipulation stuff); I have a feeling the issue here relates to the asynchronous nature of the API request and response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jasper, your correct in your assumption that it is the " asynchronous nature of the API request and response".

When you execute your http call in your `verify` service, node makes that call and them moves on to the rest of the code `console.log('vc='+vc);` and does not wait for the http call to finish.

I'm not sure what your end result should be but you can rewrite your controller / service to include the callback (this is just one options, there are many ways to do this of course, other people should suggest others)

verify.js

```
getVerifyCode: function(uuid, ip_addr, cb) {
    // Bunch of stuff
    return post_req = http.request(options, cb(post_res});
}
```

then in your controller 
controller.js

```
verify.getVerifyCode(req.session.uuid, req.connection.remoteAddress, function(resps){
    // code in here to execute when http call is finished
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the bump in the right direction!  [This read](https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node#callbacks) was helpful too.  I ended up doing something similar to what you suggested.