# Can I run a Sails.js Service synchronously?

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I have a Sails.js Service that parses an RSS feed using the [FeedParser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/feedparser) package. The service takes a single RSS feed URL, parses it, creates an array of posts and returns the array. In my controller, this is what I have:

```
var stories = RssService.fetch(rssLinks[0]);
console.log(stories);

res.json({ stories: stories }, 200);
```

However, it looks like this is an asynchronous request and as a result, the console log says `undefined` and the response inside the JSON is `null`. How do I make it so that the script waits until the RssService returns posts before I console log?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192566/why-does-my-sailsjs-service-return-undefined-to-the-calling-controller-action/26207034#26207034

Answer (score 0):

Put a callback into your service. View comments above.

Controller

```
RssService.fetch(rssLinks[0], function(err,data){

  if(err) return next(err)
  return res.json({stories:data}, 200);

});
```

Comment: It's strange. Now, the app just crashes. I am using Nodemon so I get the error: `[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart` and if I don't use Nodemon, the app just crashes without any error message. Do I have to modify the service in any way for this code to work? Here is a copy of my service: http://collabedit.com/sqv45.

Comment: How are you referencing your service then?

Comment: I'm referencing it like in your answer here. Excuse the delayed reply, didn't notice that you had answered.